# Java connect to SQL Anywhere 17

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlanywhere

I'm working on a school project and I have to connect to a database done in SQL anywhere 17 and I keep getting the flowing error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlanywhere:Tds:localhost:2638?eng="DBNAME".

Any help is welcome.

Here is the code for the class doing the connection.

```
package model;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnection {

    public class ConnectionHandler {
        ResultSet r;
        Statement s;
        String returnStatus;
    }

    private String db, user, passwd;
    private String dbUrl;
    private Connection conn;

    public DBConnection(String db, String user, String passwd, Object openserver, String databasepath) {
        this.db = db;
        this.user = user;
        this.passwd = passwd;

        dbUrl = "jdbc:sqlanywhere:Tds:localhost:2638?eng=" + db;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, passwd);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            Boolean openServer = (Boolean) openserver;
            if (openServer.booleanValue())
                try {
                    String engcommand = "dbeng12 " + databasepath + db + ".db";
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(engcommand);
                    long t0, t1;
                    t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    do {
                        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } while (t1 - t0 < 5000);
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, passwd);
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to start server. " + ex);
                }
        }
    }

    public void updateStatement(String sql, ConnectionHandler ch) {
        Integer result = new Integer(0);
        String message = null;

        if (sql.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("U"))
            message = "Number of rows updated: ";
        else if (sql.trim().substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
            message = "Number of rows inserted: ";
        else
            message = " ";

        try {
            ch.s = conn.createStatement();
            result = new Integer(ch.s.executeUpdate(sql));
            ch.returnStatus = message + result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to execute the insert/update/delete statement. " + e);
            ch.returnStatus = "Error:" + e.toString();
        }
    }

    public void returnResultSetSelectStatement(String sql, int resultsetType, ConnectionHandler ch) {
        ch.r = null;
        try {
            if (resultsetType == 1)
                ch.s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            else
                ch.s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            ch.r = ch.s.executeQuery(sql);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ch.returnStatus = e.toString();
            System.out.println("Unable to execute the returnSelectStatement. " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `sajdbc4.jar` to the classpath of your program. If you are using IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse, you can add `sajdbc4.jar` as a dependent library and NetBeans/Eclipse will automatically add it to classpath.

If you are running the above program from command line, copy `sajdbc4.jar` to the folder where the above Java program is located and then compile the file using the following command (this adds `sajdbc4.jar` to classpath),

```
javac -classpath ./sajdbc4.jar DbConnection.java
```

Run the Java program using the following command (sajdbc4.jar is added to classpath),

```
java -classpath "./sajdbc4.jar;." DbConnection
```

Alternatively you can also add the Maven dependency, if you are using Maven to build your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"jdbc:sqlanywhere:DSN=SQL Anywhere 17 Demo;Password=sql"`
http://dcx.sap.com/sqla170/en/html/3bd5b17c6c5f1014945fd2b7ec7cba6a.html